# VB or macro to exclude period of times from time duration calculation in Excel

Tags: datetime, excel, time, ticket-system, vba

I have an Excel table which contains thousands of incident tickets. Each tickets typically carried over few hours or few days, and I usually calculate the total duration by substracting opening date and time from closing date and time.

However I would like to take into account and not count the out of office hours (night time), week-ends and holidays.

I have therefore created two additional reference tables, one which contains the non-working hours (eg everyday after 7pm until 7am in the morning, saturday and sunday all day, and list of public holidays).

Now I need to find some sort of VB macro that would automatically calculate each ticket "real duration" by removing from the total ticket time any time that would fall under that list.

I had a look around this website and other forums, however I could not find what I am looking for. If someone can help me achieve this, I would be extremely grateful.

Best regards,

Alex

Comment: hi,
i'm stuck on the same problem.  can you share sample of your reference tables plz.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NETWORKDAYS](https://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/networkdays-HP005209190.aspx) function to calculate the number of working days in the interval. Actually you seem to be perfectly set up for it: it takes start date, end date and a pointer to a range of holidays. By default it counts all days non-weekend.

For calculating the intraday time, you will need some additional magic. assuming that tickets are only opened and closed in bussines hours, it would look like this:

```
first_day_hrs := dayend - ticketstart
last_day_hrs := ticketend - daystart
inbeetween_hrs := (NETWORKDAYS(ticketstart, ticketend, rng_holidays) - 2) * (dayend - daystart)

total_hrs := first_day_hrs + inbetween_hrs + last_day_hrs
```

Of course the names should in reality refer to Excel cells. I recommend using lists and/or names.

Comment: how to find "dayend" & "daystart" plz.